# Makefile:2: *** missing separator. Stop. (i tried to check if i use space instead of tab)

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, tabs

i want to command 'make' at ubuntu.

but there is something error like this

```
Makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

so i googled it, then i found that i have to check if i use the space instead of tab.

so i command

```
cat -e -t -v  makefile
```

makefile(is my Makefile name)
but still there is same error "Makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop."

i dont't know why i already checked the space and tab.

this is my output of ubuntu:

```
intro_exe : proj1.o main.o^M$
    gcc -o intro_exe proj1.o main.o^M$
main.o : main.c^M$
    gcc -c -o main.o main.c^M$
proj1.o : proj1.c^M$
    gcc -c -o proj1.o proj1.c^M$
clean : ^M$
    rm *.o intro_exe
```

i used tab at the first of line however, where is the ^I(?)? some people said if i use tab then there is ^I...

and this is my Makefile code:

```
intro_exe : proj1.o main.o
    gcc -o intro_exe proj1.o main.o
main.o : main.c
    gcc -c -o main.o main.c
proj1.o : proj1.c
    gcc -c -o proj1.o proj1.c
clean : 
    rm *.o intro_exe
```

Comment: Are you sure your editor isn't configured to turn a tab into multiple spaces?  If that really is the output of `cat -e -t -v  makefile` then your makefile doesn't contain tabs.

Comment: Also, the `^M` suggests you use MSWin line ends.

Comment: You ask _where is the ^I_.  The fact that it's missing is exactly your problem.  it's telling you that your lines _do not_ start with a TAB character, and that's why you're seeing this error.  You need to reconfigure whatever editor you're using (you don't say which one) to not replace TAB with spaces, or else find a different/better editor to edit your makefiles.  As for Windows CRLF line endings, that's OK `make` will work with either type.

Comment: Thank you for answering me! I use ubuntu, then what do i do fix this problem? 
i am googling "ubuntu tab now showing~~" but i don't know what do i have to do please help me ..